# AWS Timestream Scheduled Query runs into an "Record Already Exists" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

So, I have a table in AWS Timestream called **test-table** that has some metrics of every minute. Each record has a unique timestamp. I do not set the version explicitly for these records since they are uniquely identified by timestamp.
Now, I created a schedule query to aggregate minutes data over a window of 1 hour and write data of previous day 24-hours into a new table called **hour-table**. The query runs and writes some records as per a cron expression I gave in the AWS UI, but it keeps running into the error:
**"A record already exists with the same time, dimensions, measure name, and version {SOME_VERSION_NUBER}. A higher version is required to update the measure value."**
I only run one query at a time. My scheduled query looks like:

**SELECT
user as user,
SUM(requests) as requests,
BIN(time, 1h) AS time
FROM
"test-db"."test-table"
WHERE
time BETWEEN @scheduled_runtime - 45h and @scheduled_runtime - 21h
GROUP BY
user,
time**

The cron expression runs it at 9pm PST i.e. 4am UTC, so my cron expression is: 0 4 * * ?

---

I tried diferent ways to specify time range in WHERE clause but same error happens each time.

- BETWEEN date_trunc('day', ago(1d)) AND date_trunc('day', now())
  and
- time between bin(ago(1d), 1d) and  bin(now(), 1d)
- Also, I checked the source table has all records unique (uniquely identified by time).
- It seems that scheduled query is adding a version internally to the records. I could not find any docummentation that shows how to set up version in a scheduled query. In any case, I fail to understand how could the time, dimensions be same.

Answer (score 0):

So, Timestream uses the **dimensions and time** as primary key for a record. If you try to save the same set of dimensions + time, without "bumping" the version, you'll receive this error you're reporting.

Please, check your **Scheduled Query's query, to make sure the time and dimensions you're trying to write are not the same as the last run of the Scheduled Query**. If you're ok with overwriting data when both dimensions and time are exactly the same, you can use **`now` as EpochTimestamp as the version**, what will make each version higher than the last one thus, forcing the save.

**But watch out!** If you do that, you must make sure the query is correct, otherwise you'll be **overwriting data that you shouldn't**.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks for your suggestion. I have the same problem. However, how can I map a result column to the version, when creating the scheduled query? I tried to_milliseconds(now()) as version, but I couldn't find a way to map version to the actual version - Timestream understands it as a measure name